# When do I free an MPI sub-group?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm creating MPI groups in a loop that perform a task, but when I want to free the group, the computation aborts. When should I free the group?

The error I get is:

```
[KLArch:13617] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_free
[KLArch:13617] *** reported by process [1712324609,2]
[KLArch:13617] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[KLArch:13617] *** MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator
[KLArch:13617] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[KLArch:13617] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[KLArch:13611] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[KLArch:13611] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

What I intend to do is to do a calculation with an increasing number of processes in parallel as a benchmark for MPI, i.e. doing the whole calculation with only 1 processe, take the time, run the same calculation with 2 processes, take the time, run the same calculation with 4 processes, take the time... and compare how the problem scales with the number of processes.

MWE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int rank = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // Get the group of processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD
    MPI_Group world_group;
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);

    // Construct a group containing all of the ranks smaller than i in MPI_COMM_WORLD
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        int group_ranks[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            group_ranks[j] = j;
        }

        // Construct a group with all the ranks smaller than i
        MPI_Group sub_group;
        MPI_Group_incl(world_group, i, group_ranks, &sub_group);

        // Create a communicator based on the group
        MPI_Comm sub_comm;
        MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, sub_group, &sub_comm);

        int sub_rank = -1;
        int sub_size = -1;
        // If this rank isn't in the new communicator, it will be
        // MPI_COMM_NULL. Using MPI_COMM_NULL for MPI_Comm_rank or
        // MPI_Comm_size is erroneous
        if (MPI_COMM_NULL != sub_comm)
        {
            MPI_Comm_rank(sub_comm, &sub_rank);
            MPI_Comm_size(sub_comm, &sub_size);
        }

        // Do some work
        printf("WORLD RANK/SIZE: %d/%d \t Group RANK/SIZE: %d/%d\n",
               rank, size, sub_rank, sub_size);

        // Free the communicator and group
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //MPI_Comm_free(&sub_comm);
        //MPI_Group_free(&sub_group);
        j = 0;
    }
    MPI_Group_free(&world_group);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The code throws the error, if I uncomment `MPI_Comm_free(&sub_comm);` and `MPI_Group_free(&sub_group);` at the end of the loop.

Comment: you cannot `MPI_Comm_free(MPI_COMM_NULL)`

Comment: Thank you, @GillesGouaillardet. Writing it as `if (sub_comm != MPI_COMM_NULL){MPI_Comm_free(&sub_comm);}` solved the problem. :) Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me collect some remarks about this code.

1. that barrier is not needed.
2. if you test this on a multi-node system you have to be aware that your processes are not spread evenly: 13 processes on 3 6-core nodes would give you  6+6+1 which is unbalanced. You would want 5+4+4 or so. Your `mpiexec` would do this correctly; achieving this in your code is a little harder. Just be aware of this since you are doing benchmarking.
3. It's a little tricky getting this code right. When you make a subgroup, all processes have the same value for the group, including the ones that are not in the group. For instance they do not get `MPI_GROUP_NULL`. Then you have to call `MPI_Comm_create` collectively on the large communicator; processes that are not in the group get `MPI_COMM_NULL` as result. They do not participate in the actions on the subcommunicator. Also, and this was your problem: they do not free the subcommunicator, but they do free the subgroup.

(That last point was also pointed out by @GillesGouaillardet)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Victor-Eijkhout! Would there be a better of to define the subgroups than using `MPI_Comm_create`?

Comment: @kalle If you're referring to point 2, the problem is not with the create call, but with you you construct the group. You'd have to be much more clever in what ranks to pick. Do you indeed have a multi-node system?

Comment: I'm testing this code on a Ryzen 3950X, so it's only one CPU socket with 16 physical and 32 logical threads. What I'm trying to achieve is a code that performs a simple calculation first in just 1 thread, then in 2 threads, then in 4 threads... and compares the computation times. But I'm not set on achieving this with subgroups!

Comment: @kalle On a single socket you should be good.